# Migrate phpBB forum to phpFox

Tags: migration, phpbb, phpfox

I am struggling to find a migration tool from phpBB to phpFox. It seems that there is no ready made script so I would have to do it myself. I want to use the default phpFox forum.

I would appreciate some insight if anyone has done a similar thing. Or if it is possible to somehow integrate phpBB with phpFox?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to migrate. posts, user data, categories etc